# How to find out the dimensions of an image

Tags: python

[image]

I am using this python code to read this image file

```
image = img.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/rusty.png')
```

How do I determine the dimension of this image array?
I printed out `len(image), len(image[0])` and `len(image[0][0])`
Which probably shows what's the len of each submatrix...

Comment: Hello joseph, what librairie are you using for img.imread, is it openCV (cv2) or matplotlib.pyplot ? In either ways if your variable image is a numpy array (which is very likely and checkable by printing type(image)), you can just print image.shape to get the size of the image (height, width, channels)

Comment: import matplotlib.image as img

Answer (score 0):

Use `shape` to find the dimensions of an object [Reference link](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-get-image-size/)

`image.shape`

> images are stored in numpy ndarray. To get the image shape or size, use `ndarray.shape` to get the dimensions of the image. Then, you can use index on the dimensions variable to get width, height and number of channels for each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

convert list to `nparray`:

```
import numpy as np

image=np.array(image) 
print(image.shape)
```